# Coverage.py: include only parts of file

Tags: python, report, code-coverage, coverage.py

I have a large python file where data (90%) is mixed with logic.
Refactoring the logic out is unfortunately not an option. But I want to generate separate coverage reports for logic and data parts.
Here is more or less how the file looks like:

```
class Mapping1(BaseMapping):
  mapping = "label 1"

class Mapping2(BaseMapping):
  mapping = "label 2"

# many more BaseMappings follow...

class Mapping456(LogicMapping):
  mapping = "label 456"
  @classmethod
  def additional_logic(cls): # I want to get coverage for this separately
      <some code here>

class Mapping457(LogicMapping):
  mapping = "label 457"
  @classmethod
  def additional_logic(cls): # I want to get coverage for this separately
      <some code here>

class Mapping458(BaseMapping):
  mapping = "label 458"

# many more BaseMappings follow...
```

What I would need is an `include_lines` option for *coverage*, so I can do it like this:
**.coveragerc_data**

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
  def additional_logic
```

**.coveragerc_logic**

```
[report]
include_lines =
  def additional_logic
```

But this is not possible as there's no "include_lines" option in *coverage*.

I also tried this:
**.coveragerc_logic**

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
  BaseMapping
```

Which is not a perfect solution as there are sometimes `LogicMapping`s that don't include `additional_logic` definition apparently.
Also this way the coverage will include the "mapping" lines for logic classes. Which in real world are 1-6 values per class so this will pollute the coverage report.

Moving the logical parts to another file will unfortunately require a larger refactoring, as there's some import-magic associated with that file in other parts of the codebase to get the "mappings".

As I want to get reports for both parts, manually excluding data part with `#pragma: no cover` is also not an option. As I need to generate coverage report for 10% of code scattered across the file, I'm interested in **selective inclusion** rather than exclusion.

Any suggestions that will help me avoid a major refactor are welcome.